# Resultado de Busqueda en Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Haciendo una búsqueda en Laravel, me da la busqueda bien en cuanto a nombre pero no en ID.

Es decir.

Esta es la lista de objetos

```
<div class="panel-body-exercises">
             <h1 class="hidden">List of Exercise </h1>  
                <ul class="list-group">

                    <li class="list-group-item" id="data"></li>
                    @foreach($exercises as $exercise)

                        <li class="list-group-item" > 
                        <a id="name" href="/exercises/{{ $exercise->id }}" >  {{ $exercise->name}}</a></li>
                     @endforeach
                </ul> 
        </div>
```

Aquí hago la busqueda de acuerdo a su nombre

```
('#form').on('input',function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            exercise = $(this).serialize();
            $.post('/getSearch', exercise, function(search)

            {

                $('#data').html('');
                $.each(search, function (key,data){

                    $('#data').append(''+


                    '<li class="list-group-item" id="data"> <a id="name" href="/exercises/{{ $exercise->id }}" >'+data.name+'</a></li>'+  '');

                });

            });
        });
    });
```

Me da el resultado bien, pero cuando le doy click me sale ID de otro objeto y no el señalado.
COmo si

```
 <a id="name" href="/exercises/{{ $exercise->id }}" >'+data.name+'</a> Tiene algún error.
```

Este es mi controlador, dónde hace la búsqueda.

```
public function search(Request $req)
    {
        $exercises= Exercise::all();
        return view ('exercises.index', compact ('exercises'));
    }


    public function getSearch (Request $req)
    {
        if($req->ajax())
        {
            $find= Exercise::where('name', 'LIKE','%' .$req->search. '%' )->get();
            return response()->json($find);

        }
    }
```

¿Qué puede estar mal?

Answer (score 0):

Si el link lo estas generando con lo que traes de tu ajax deberias usar el id de esos datos y no el de laravel, o sea:

En vez de:

```
'<li class="list-group-item" id="data"> <a id="name" href="/exercises/{{ $exercise->id }}" >'+data.name+'</a></li>'
```

Deberia ser:

```
'<li class="list-group-item" id="data"> <a id="name" href="/exercises/'+data.id+'" >'+data.name+'</a></li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema esta aquí:

```
 <li class="list-group-item" id="data"> <a id="name" href="/exercises/{{ $exercise->id }}" >'+data.name+'</a></li>'+  '');
```

`{{ $exercise->id }}` este código esta haciendo referencia a un mismo objs de php.

y cuando estas renderizando con javascript siempre va a tener el mismo valor.

Debes poner:

```
<li class="list-group-item" id="data"> <a id="name" href="/exercises/'+data.id +'" >'+data.name+'</a></li>'+  '');
```

`data.id` vendrá en respuesta json desde el server y con el valor correspondiente a cada resultado